# How to regex_replace that with PHP?

Tags: php, regex

This is my string:

*Versandkosten (Versand - Kosten)(innerhalb Deutschlands)*

I want to replace the first part in parentheses, so after replacing it should look like that:

*Versandkosten (innerhalb Deutschlands)*

The first part is not always the same, but its always this pattern: (something - something).

This is what I tried, but it always replaces everything:

```
$title = 'Versandkosten (Versand - Kosten)(innerhalb Deutschlands)';
$title = preg_replace('/\(.+[-].+\)/', '', $title);
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: actually, your current regex matches **(** Versand **-** Kosten)(innerhalb Deutschlands **)** .

Comment: Yeah, I know ;)... but how do I make it match only the first part?

Comment: try replacing your dots with `[a-zA-Z ]`. Complete with any sign that might be contained in the name, or use `\w`. The important part is that it doesn't contain `(` or `)`. As dots means "any character" in regex, `(` is considered valid and is captured in your regex

Comment: What if input is `Versandkosten (Versand)(innerhalb Deutschlands)` what output do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~\([^)-]*-[^)]*\)~', '', $yourstring);
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/5), look at the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- `( matches the opening parenthesis
- `[^)-]*` matches any chars that are neither a `)` nor a `-`
- `-` matches the hyphen
- `[^)]*` matches any chars that are not a `)`
- `) matches the closing parenthesis
- We replace with the empty string

Comment: FYI, added full explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$re = "/^([^()]*)\([^)]*\)(.*)$/m"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '\1\2', $input);
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vA1hO7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex if you want to remove the first `()` paranthesis.

```
(^.*?)(\([^\)]*\))
```

Your code would be,

```
<?php
$string = 'Versandkosten (Versand - Kosten)(innerhalb Deutschlands)';
$pattern = "~(^.*?)(\([^\)]*\))~";
$replacement = "$1";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?> //=> Versandkosten (innerhalb Deutschlands)
```